# How to align section heading left with revtex4-1

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, revtex

I am using `revtex4-1` and section headings are aligned in the center. How do I modify this?

Comment: If you're using RevTeX for a submission, just do nothing of this kind: the copy editors won't be happy.

Comment: REVTeX 4 has been updated to REVTeX 4.1. FYI.

Comment: The formatting of section titles depends on the options passed to the class; can you add a minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `rmp` option (`\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}`) adjusts the formatting for Rev. Mod. Phys., which has left-aligned headings.

This also works for the older REVTeX4.

Here is an example.

```
\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1-3]
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: NOO. It didn't work! I have revtex-4.1

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could provide a MWE (see @egreg's comment to your question).

Answer (score 1):

you can use titlesec package to modify the way headings are display (read pack man) in the revtex style, or try one of this

```
\begin{flushright}\section{Right align section}\end{flushright}  

\begin{flushleft}\section{Left align section}\end{flushleft}
```

Comment: NOO. It didn't work! I have revtex-4.1